# MySQL Save File to Database

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm struggling to save a file to my MySQL database.

I managed to save a image to the database with this code

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.NorthWestConnectionString);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From MyImages", con);
SqlCommandBuilder MyCB = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
DataSet ds = new DataSet("MyImages");

da.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Ruan\Downloads\Gone Fishing.BMP", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read);

byte[] MyData = new byte[fs.Length];
fs.Read(MyData, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));

fs.Close();

da.Fill(ds, "MyImages");

DataRow myRow;
myRow = ds.Tables["MyImages"].NewRow();

myRow["Description"] = "This would be description text";
myRow["imgField"] = MyData;
ds.Tables["MyImages"].Rows.Add(myRow);
da.Update(ds, "MyImages");

txtboxPassword.Text = MyData.ToString();
con.Close();
```

But the thing is that this adds a new line. I simply want to add an image/doc to an existing row. (Preferably a document)

I usually use this code to update fields in my db.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.Studentsdb1ConnectionString;
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
String SQL = String.Format("UPDATE Students SET First_Name = '{0}' , Last_Name = '{1}', Birth_Date = '{2}' WHERE Student_Nr = '{3}'", txtName.Text, txtSurname.Text, Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Text).ToString("d"), SelectedStudentNr);


cmd.CommandText = SQL;

cmd.Connection = conn;

object result = null;
ConnectionState previousConnectionState = conn.State;
try
{
if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
conn.Open();
}
result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}


finally
{
if (previousConnectionState == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
conn.Close();
}
```

So now I can't seem to store a file? I am missing something somewhere.

Could you please help me out?

Comment: Its kind a bad idea to store binary file data in the DB, although most of the newer versions of DB allows it. I would say bringing that much data back and forth from the DB all the time will impact performance. My suggestion would be to save the path of where it lives on the server in the DB instead..

Comment: MySql? the code seems to be in MS SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`SqlParameter` type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) and pass them to your `SqlCommand`, not only for images but for any kind (it's more secure and goes in "natural" way).

Comment: Okyyy, i get i get, so its not just for images... Thank you Petr.

Comment: Oh yes, and would you please tell me where i mark this question as solved?